# Missing hyperlinks and wrong page numbering while including pdf files in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, fancyhdr, pdfpages

I am creating a dynamic table of contents by adding pdf files. Following are the problems

1. Original pdf files have hyper links which disappear after putting together with table of contents. How to maintain the hyper links in the final output?
2. How to remove the page number from the table of contents page and start from the page 'Cover_Letter'?

Following is my attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=1in, footskip=.7in]{geometry}

\fancypagestyle{includedpages}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%        
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Cover Letter}% or chapter
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{includedpages} }, pages=-]{Cover_Letter.pdf}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Curriculum Vitae}% or chapter
\includepdf[pagecommand={ \thispagestyle{includedpages}}, pages=-]{CV.pdf}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Teaching Statement}% or chapter
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{includedpages}}, pages=-]{Statement1.pdf}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Research Statement}% or chapter
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{includedpages} }, pages=-]{Statement2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See the `pdfpages` documentation. Hyperlinks are always lost but there is a workaround there which might be able to put them back (but I've never tried it personally). If you use `\pagestyle{empty}` won't that work as you want them empty except once you start including the PDFs? If you want the page numbers always on the left, why are you testing whether the pages are odd or not?

Comment: @cfr Edited the question. Page numbers on the left is solved.